# How can I convert an iOS (objective-c) NSString value to a byte value?

Tags: objective-c

How can I convert an iOS (objective-c) NSString value to a byte value?

JAVA uses `.getBytes()`, but I do not know how to do it on iOS.

```
uint8_t *dbytes = (uint8_t *)[Value bytes];
```

I expected to be something like this… but I do not want it.

Comment: It's unclear what exact result you want but start by looking at the reference documentation for `NSString` and also review [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bobjective-c%5D+nsstring+bytes).

Comment: You do not want it? Why?

Answer (score 0):

You can call `-[NSString UTF8String]` to change NSString into `const char*`.

Example: `const char *bytes = [Value UTF8String];`

Reference: [Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring?language=objc)

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear in what encoding you expect your results to be.
Java's `getBytes()` returns String bytes using default encoding which is platform dependant, so instead use `getBytes(charsetname)` providing charset explicitly. You should communicate to use a specific encoding to avoid interoperability issues.

On iOS side, you can use `-[NSStrings dataUsingEncoding:]`

e.g.

```
NSData *bytes = [@"Hello" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

First, use `UTF8String` translate to `unsigned long`, then use `0xff &` translate to Byte, as below:

```
NSString *str =@"xxx";
unsigned long red = strtoul([str UTF8String], 0, 16);
Byte bt = (Byte)(0xff & red);
```